# Cannot push to Git with IntelliJ Idea12

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I recently updated to IntelliJ idea 12, and I am unable to Push to Git.  The error message I am getting is

```
8:02:10 AM Push failed: Couldn't authorize
```

I can push without issue using Tortoise Git.  I am thinking this stems from my password changing for LDAP, however I cannot find anywhere to change the saved Git password in IntelliJ.

I have tried changing the master password but that did not resolve the issue.

I can pull without issue.

Comment: same problem here, changed password, and then forever not able to push, even after deleting .idea folder

Comment: Looks like this will be fixed in 13.1.3  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just backed off to 11.1.5 since intellij 12 git support seems totally hosed.

Comment: I will open a ticket with JetBrains. I tried in 11.1 also and it worked there.

Comment: I wiped the .IntelliJIdea12 directory and that "resolved" the issue I was having and I was prompted for credentials again. However I am still working the devteam for JetBrains to get it so credentials can be updated.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to open a request [in the tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) and attach the log there (Help -> Reveal Log).

Btw, to remove all passwords from IDEA for sure you have to restart after resetting the master password, because passwords may be saved to memory as well.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late answer, but I've experienced this problem too (as recent as today), and I have an easy "fix" for it until JetBrains fix it.

Instead of wiping the entire `.IntelliJIdea12 folder`, which will result in you loosing all settings, you can simply delete the `security.xml` file in `~\.IntelliJIdea12\config\options` and restart IDEA. Now you will be prompted to enter credentials again, and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to fully reinstall IDEA v.12**, deleting all local history and cleaning register.
I'm using IntellijIDEA on many computers. This problem occures randomly on some of them.
 This radical method helped somehow solve the problem (but not on all computers).

Comment: Actually you do not need to do a full re-install, if you wipe the .intelliJIdea12 directory in the user profile that takes care of it.  However I did let jetbrains know about this bug and they are working on it.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty heavy handed. reminds me of last week when my keyboard's firmware wouldn't install and they told me to literally reinstall my entire OS to fix it. Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij IDEA on mac delete this directories:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/
```

As read in [In IntelliJ on OS X, how do you clear out all global setting info, licensing etc. (external to any project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774315/in-intellij-on-os-x-how-do-you-clear-out-all-global-setting-info-licensing-etc)

Answer (score 0):

For the IntelliJ Community Edition, the security.xml file is in .IdeaIC12/config/options:
http://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/fix-password-issues-in-intellij-12/

Answer (score 0):

in your project folder, go to .git folder (you will not see it in windows, just type it in address bar) and edit url in config file (issue still exists in intellij 13.1.3)