# IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 eat 100% CPU from time to time

Tags: intellij-idea, cpu-usage

I've just updated my IntelliJ IDEA to latest 12.1 version and I found my laptop CPU usage become 100% from time to time, monitor the progress manager I found IDEA fork an new Java process regularly and it runs for several tens of seconds and shutdown. During that time the CPU usage is close to 100%:[image: the screen capture]

Comment: I use IntellJ too, It has never eaten 100% cpu, the problem whether is that there are too many moduls in your project? maybe help you. P.S. Are you from China?

Comment: This may be an effect of automatic [external build enabled](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3550/20121206235318.png). If you are using Scala, it will also run compilation in background.

Comment: I am not using Scala. All pure Java.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, hello! It seems that for IDEA13 settings page was changed. How to disable automatic external build now in v.13.1? thank you!

Comment: @java_newbie this question is obsolete. If you have problems, contact support with the [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118). You can't disable external build in IDEA 13.

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 5):

Chances are the external build mentionned by @CrazyCoder compiles your project automatically when you make changes to your source files. If it annoys you too much, you can disable automatic compilation in `File > Settings > Compiler > Make project automatically` (uncheck the box).

Comment: Is it a 12.1 specific configuration? I don't have the prob on 12.04

Comment: No, this external build system was introduced in IntelliJ 12, but it may have changed a little bit in 12.1. I disabled this option in 12.0 because mu current laptop doesn't like it very much :)

Comment: there's no such checkbox in IDEA13, so how do you deal with it now?

Answer (score 3):

I had the IDEA 12 process itself (not a forked Java) occupy 100%, and respond very slowly to keypresses, navigation, etc.

Eventually I resolved this by **cleaning out the cache, prefs, Application Support dir, etc and uninstalling/reinstalling** IDEA 12. You have to reinstate your preferences and let Idea reindex your projects (due to removing its cache) - but this shouldn't take long.

Here's a [list of some places to clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774369/863802) on OS X (slightly out of date for IDEA 12, but a useful starting point).

Comment: This worked for me with IDEA 13 on OSX Mavericks. Thank you! Made a huge difference. Well worth the effort to go through the re-install.

Comment: File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart  .. did the trick for me. Before that the CPU usage was upwards of 60% and restarting IntelliJ alone did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I am using IntelliJ 13 Community Edition and have found this problem on Linux.
It my case it is the Intelli JBehave plugin causing these issues.

When opening a dialog the CPU usage of the Java process drops right back to 5 to 10% percent.
When disabling the plugin the same is true.

Comment: I am having this same issue with IDEA 13 Ultimate on Linux Mint 17 (insane, 100% load which drops to 5% when a dialog is opened). I can't find a plugin called "JBehave" or "Behave" though. Are you sure it is called like this?

Comment: Yes that's what it is called. Perhaps could be another plugin?

Answer (score -4):

Goto Home Folder then Navigate to .IntelliJIdea13\config\options

Edit the file "project.default.xml" Change the VM_PARAMETERS Xmx and Xms as follows

It decreased the CPU usage to 50%