# Launching Ruby-Cucumber from IntelliJ (OSX)

Tags: ruby, macos, intellij-idea, cucumber

I am in a new job and am using IntelliJ with Ruby and Cucumber.. all of which are new to me.

I have a working project based upon this project: https://github.com/jonathanchrisp/selenium-cucumber-ruby-kickstarter

So, from the command line, I run my project like this:

```
  sudo cukesparse something
```

cukesparse is not my project but here is a quick description from github: "A simple command line parser to pass default and custom arguments into Cucumber with the power to define these as tasks in a config/tasks.yml file!"
(seems interesting enough to me)

So, from the command line I am able to execute this project without any problems.  I am also able to "Build > Rebuild Project" without issue.

My question is regarding getting a Run Config to work.  I have tried to go to Run > Edit Configurations, but have had no luck creating a config to start my run.  When I try to click Ruby from the list of 'base configurations', IntelliJ doesn't seem to want me to pick it.  The UI sort of doesn't respond.

I must be stuck with some obvious newbie booboo.  Any tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't ever get to the bottom of exactly what the issue was, but completely removing IntelliJ (using the comment from Jenny here: [In IntelliJ on OS X, how do you clear out all global setting info, licensing etc. (external to any project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774315/in-intellij-on-os-x-how-do-you-clear-out-all-global-setting-info-licensing-etc)) and reinstalling with a very minimal plugin set fixed it.  I basically only enabled the git plugin, then got the ruby plugin from the repository and no other plugins.

I did need to add the cucumber gem from the command line but that didn't turn out to be part of the problem.  Something about the plugins I had selected was making some of the Run Configurations not function.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IntelliJ are you using? And do you have the Ruby and Base Cucumber plugins installed in IntelliJ? (From Intellij -> preferences -> Plugins). If not, the first step would be to install those.

Then you can create a run configuration by Run > Edit Configurations, selecting the required details. If you have further issues, a screengrab of your configuration (from Run > Edit Configurations) would be helpful.