# IntelliJ/MacOSX - Unable to view Rake 'Run Configuration' form

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, rake

I had previously posted this question: [Launching Ruby-Cucumber from IntelliJ (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958637/launching-ruby-cucumber-from-intellij-osx) and didn't get any responses so I am trying to generalize further and have discovered that I am simply not seeing some screens in IntelliJ on MacOSX.

Here is the screen I seek on Windows 7:
[Screenshot on win7](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/17705/596083/PUR4bHFwwwxRDCp/win7rakeForm.png)

This is the Run > "Edit Run Configurations" > + > Rake screen in IntelliJ with the Ruby plugin.

On OSX, IntelliJ seems to be preventing me from selecting Ruby related Run Configurations. Attempts to click Rake don't result in the text being highlighted and the form doesn't show.  I have no trouble seeing the configuration forms for Javascript, Java, Groovy, Flash, etc.

I am new to Ruby, but even newer to OSX.  Has anyone ever seen this behavior using IntelliJ with the Ruby plugin?  Is there a resolution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer here:
[Launching Ruby-Cucumber from IntelliJ (OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958637/launching-ruby-cucumber-from-intellij-osx)

I must have had some plugins that were causing problems with eachother.