# Can't run Intellij IDEA13 Ultimate on OSX (CE work proper)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Idea 13 Ultimate, Idea CE 13, OSX 10.9.3

Yesterday every thing with my Idea13U were be ok but now i got an error. Before this problem i'm do not instal any updates, programs and do not change any parameter of the OS. (Idea 13 CE work proper)

```
...$ open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13.app/
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app with error -10810.
```

After googling i try few recommendations but it doesn't have effect.

1. Install 'Java for OS X 2014-001' and actual version of Oracle JDK7
2. reDownload IDEA13 ultimate from Intellij site and put it in /Application folder
3. Changed in file /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist JDK version 1.6*->1.7*
4. Already enabled Settings/Security & Privacy - 'application from all sources'
5. reboot

Also i'm download Idea13 Community edition and it work proper with the same settings.

Result of 'java_home -V shows' :

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
1.7.0_60, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
1.7.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Help me please, I can't work! :((

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Java applications fail silently on OS X Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594627/open-java-applications-fail-silently-on-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: I found interesting thing. IDEA 13 Community Edition work proper with the same settings and JDK1.6* in Info.plst file.  Makoto, thank you for you link but it is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program worked after deleting all configuration files as it is described in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774369/2253090).

Answer (score 1):

For the following error:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh

e2015-03-18 21:02:24.425 idea[962:382297] No matching VM found.
[JavaAppLauncher Error] CFBundleCopyResourceURL() failed loading MRJApp.properties file
[JavaAppLauncher Error] CFBundleCopyResourceURL() failed while getting Resource/Java directory
[LaunchRunner Error] No main class specified
[JavaAppLauncher Error] CallStaticVoidMethod() threw an exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:113)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
    at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.main(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:61)
```

Remember to set the JAVA_HOME variable in .bash_profile correctly:

```
export JAVA_HOME= /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
```

after downloading the Regular Oracle JAVA JDK

If this does not work - download the **Java for OS X 2014-001**
from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US)

---

You can also edit the file:
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

and change 1.6 to **1.8**