# Unable to to load Tomcat plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am running IntelliJ 15 Ultimate and trying to enable the Tomcat plugin (which for some reason was disabled). However, IntelliJ does not seem to let me re-enable it.

[image]

What I have tried is

- Re-install IntelliJ 15, and I chose to replace the old version, but the problems with the plugin seem to be persistent
- Deleting `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/plugins/Tomcat` between the re-installs to ensure it was not being re-used, but with no avail
- Verifying that I have a licensed/paid version of IntelliJ 15 Ultimate edition

At this point I'm not sure what to do, as a re-install clearly did not work. Are there any directories or files I could manually change/remove?

I am using OS X version 10.11.2 is that matters.

Comment: I'm using WIN so I can't verify on MAC, but I believe it'd be similar. IJ usually has a `.IntelliJIdea<VERSION>` folder in your home dir. Can you check whether it's writeable?

Comment: Issue solved for me after [enabling Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/enabling-jpa-support.html#plugin). You don't need to re-install idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with was to entirely wipe IntelliJ and any config files it created as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774369/490315).

Upon installing IntelliJ once again, the Tomcat plugin was enabled and was able to create a run configuration for that! Maybe not a fix per se, but it works as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" plugin as well. The message is displayed because that plugin is not enabled, and the Tomcat plugin depends on it.

Comment: I tried that, but the same error message appeared when trying to enable these. They were enabled but when i tried to toggle them off and on again, I got the same error message.